# Program getting struck near malloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have use the code like below

```
char *es_data;

fp_input = fopen(inp_path, "rb");

fseek(fp_input, 0, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(fp_input);
fseek(fp_input, 0, SEEK_SET);

es_data = (char*)malloc(file_size);
fread(es_data, 1, file_size, fp_input);
```

I have a file of 185mb, i.e., file_size = 190108334 bytes. For this file, malloc is crashing, and program is getting struck at this stage.
If i use any other file of lower size, it works fine. 
What can I do ?

Comment: check for `fp_input` being NULL and also check for `es_data` being NULL. And [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: First thing to do... Always check the return value of malloc().

Comment: What is your platform? Compiler? Is this 32/64 bit? And most importantly - did you make sure the `fp_input = fopen(inp_path, "rb");` succeeded? Because if it didn't...

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`, it's `void*` and compatible to any pointer in `C`. Any cast can hide errors that the compiler could detect and indicate with a diagnostic messages. Further the readability gets worse with casts.

Comment: `malloc` is a system function is isn't known for crashing. Is your problem that `malloc` returns a NULL pointer? Change your code to check the return value.

Comment: Is program crashing (terminating) or getting stuck (becomes unresponsive but does not terminate)?

Comment: Also, check return values of all functions, especially `ftell` before giving it to `malloc`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test at least that `fopen` succeeds:

```
 fp_input = fopen(inp_path, "rb");
 if (!fp_input) { popen(inp_path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Your `malloc` is probably not crashing, but *failing* (by returning `NULL`): read [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) so code at least:

```
 es_data = malloc(file_size);
 if (!es_data) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

BTW, you probably want to [memory map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) a file. If you are on Linux or a Posix system, learn about [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (and use [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) to query the size of an [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ed file descriptor). Windows can also memory map  a file with [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537.aspx)

If your `malloc` is indeed *crashing* this probably means that you have [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) (before that `malloc` call) so some internal invariant of your system `malloc` is violated. Use some [memory debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger) tool (like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on Linux, or [purify](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ratpurwin/) on Windows) to detect it.

Comment: THanks for the answer. Am using Windows now and fopen is not crashing, that I have checking every time.

Comment: `fopen` won't *crash* but could *fail* (and ditto for `malloc`).